# MySQL PHP Continue results beyond LIMIT

Tags: php, mysql, limit

I require to output only 35 results per tab within a JQuery UI.

Each Tab shall represent a page of 35 results by increment.

[image: JQuery Tab UI Example]

I am not entirely familiar with the use of `LIMIT` and thus far i cannot seem to understand the correct way to utilize its function to achieve my desired result perhaps solely within a degree of my urge to ensure efficiency but nonetheless i would like to learn about the possibilities.

I have a MySQL Query as follows:

```
 $sql13x = " SELECT * 
                FROM item_groups 
                    WHERE section_id='$item_sec_id' 
                    AND item_sub_sec_id='$item_sub_sec_id' 
                    ORDER BY item_id ASC LIMIT 35";
```

From this point i am able to acquire 35 results, but how do i commence beyond that?
Baring in mind each 35 results is responsible for creating the tab as well as the `div` below holding the results.

Is there an ability to continue a query beyond where you stopped previously? Or do i have to make a count with `PHP` and resend the query removing the total number of results counted?

Even though i could achieve the desired result, this is a query of the "right" way to achieve the result, either through efficiency and or dynamic ability. Also in general to learn if i am missing something.

Comment: Limit can take two arguments, the starting point and the total amount.  So for instance LIMIT 0,35 starts at the first record and shows 35.  If you want records 36-70, do LIMIT 35,35.  Then limit 70,35 and so on.

Comment: if you do LIMIT 0,35 does it work? - then you need 35,35 for the next 35 results

Comment: `LIMIT 35` will only get at most 35 records from the table (matching your `where` clause).  In your case, you probably need to load all (remove `LIMIT` from your query) and then in your code split it in groups of 35, creating a new tab for each group.

Comment: Andrew should write his answer to get points since hes only got 87 ;)

Comment: I guess.  I'm always a bit afraid to try to answer because I still feel like a n00b and worry I might be missing something obvious, ha ha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Limit can take two arguments, the starting point and the total amount. So for instance LIMIT 0,35 starts at the first record and returns 35 records. If you want records 36-70, do LIMIT 35,35. Then limit 70,35 and so on.

Comment: What if, I want ALL results, from 36 onwards? Not just 36-70, but 36 to the end (without knowing how many records are there in total)
Any thoughts?

Comment: MySQL reference says this, which is sort of surprising because it seems like a bad hack:  "To retrieve all rows from a certain offset up to the end of the result set, you can use some large number for the second parameter. This statement retrieves all rows from the 96th row to the last:

SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 95,18446744073709551615;"

Comment: Yes. I also read that, but it just sounds like such a bad hack, that I couldn't believe there wasn't a more elegant way to do it!